# Using Iterable to iterate over an ArrayList?

Tags: java, foreach

We all know this piece of code:

```
ArrayList<String> str1 = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String str: str1) {
    // code goes here
}
```

This enhanced-for loop uses an Iterable instead of `Iterator` to traverse. But I didn't see that `ArrayList` extends `Iterable`. Could anyone tell me why this can happen?

Comment: The docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) clearly show `Interable<E>` in the list of what it implements.

Comment: It's "syntactic sugar," so even for something like an array, it doesn't necessary need to be tied to a special construct

Comment: You didn't find it where? Both the Javadoc and 'javap' say it does extend 'Iterable'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ArrayList` extends [`AbstractList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) which implements `Iterable`

Comment: ArrayList also implements List, which extends Iterable.